# CSS equally divide children width if they don't fit in the parent

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal list of dynamically added elements (using float:left). It's something like taskbar or tabbar in web browsers. Li elements have certain fixed width, but when there are too many elements and they wouldn't fit in the parent with their width, their widths are divided equally. I implemented it in JavaScript. Each time an element is added to the list, the total width of elements is computed and if it's greater than parent width, new width is applied. I never wondered if it's possible in CSS, it's a JS application after all, so there's nothing wrong with using JS to compute it. But if it could be done in CSS entirely, it would simplify things for me.

In other words, I ask if it's possible to do something like browser tab bar with pure CSS.

Comment: You should look into flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe suggested [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is probably your best hope for this. I also added text-overflow to my demonstration:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display:flex;
}
li {
  max-width: 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  flex:1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
  <li>Item9</li>
  <li>Item10</li>
  <li>Item11</li>
  <li>Item12</li>
  <li>Item13</li>
  <li>Item14</li>
  <li>Item15</li>
  <li>Item16</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I've been looking for.